# How do I unwrap all parents using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<p><span><a href="link"></a></span></p>
```

How would I unwrap everything leaving just `<a href="link"></a>`?

-edit-

Sorry, I should have provided more information. Basically, I'm trying to target all `a`'s that are the only child of `span`'s which are surrounded by `p` tags. I was hoping the following would do the trick but it only unwrapped the `p` tags. I was wondering if there was a way to remove the `span` tags as well.

`$('p > span:only-child > a:only-child').unwrap();`

Comment: By "unwrap", you mean you want to remove the `p` and `span` tags from the DOM while leaving the `a` there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var link = $("a").detach();
    $("p").remove();
    link.appendTo("body");
});
```

Detaches the link from the DOM and sets it aside in the `link` var.  Entirely removes the `p` from the DOM.  Reattaches the `a` to the `body` tag.

To put the link back precisely where it is, append it to the parent of the `p`, not necessarily the `body` element.  So let's say you've got this:

```
<div id="foo">
<p><span><a href="link"></a></span></p>
</div>
```

You'd use this line instead:

```
link.appendTo("#foo");
```

**Edit in response to your edit:**

Yes, unwrap only does one parent level (as far as I know).  So just do it two times. :)

```
$('p > span:only-child > a:only-child').unwrap().unwrap();
```

Comment: @Steve, I would use this instead.

Comment: Thank you, Jeff. Just to be clear and because I realized how simple and uninformative my original post was, I added a bit more info to reflect exactly what I want done. Does your answer still apply?

Comment: It should still apply if you know which element to reattach the link to - that's the key.  I didn't think `unwrap()` would work at first since it only unwraps one level, but then I realized you could just call it twice.  First to remove the `span`, second to remove the `p`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information about the other elements on the page. The following is just to get you started.

```
var theLink = $("span").html();
$("p").remove();
$("body").html(theLink);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I've provided more information in my original post.